# Jackson Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
```

I am mapping(many to many) to entities in hibernate while mapping i am getting this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We cannot help you with this little information.